# Why must Membership Provider be specified

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to make my own login functionality without using Membership Provider, but after I login using the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login` control and set the authentication cookie using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, rememberMe);`

I got the following error message

> Default Membership Provider must be specified.

I wonder why it must be specified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could use it without making my own login form. I've just removed the membership provider section from the webconfig.

Answer (score 2):

The `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login` is tightly coupled to the Membership Providers.  If you want to log in without a Membership Provider, you should just make your own login form with textboxes and buttons.

Comment: Thanks, I could use it without making my own login form. I've just removed the membership provider section from the webconfig.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I just stumbled across the question and since I've done this wanted to share my solution in case anyone else should have need.

The catch is you need to handle the `OnAuthenticate` event of the `asp:Login` control.  In the simplest form you would have this in the aspx:

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">
</asp:Login>
```

And this in the code behind:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) {
    e.Authenticated = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password);
}
```

And this in web.config:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" path="/" protection="None" name="user_login_cookie">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="user" password="password_in_clear!"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

This will get you a simple login form with a hardcoded user in web.config.  Good for prototypes and demos, please don't put user accounts in web.configs for live sites!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a section to your web.config telling it where to look for your membership roster.  this will be either a database containing users, an active directory group, etc.  otherwise, how does your app know where to authenticate your users?

Check out [MSDN's Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) for more information.